# Virtuemart datepicker doesn't work in chrome

Tags: jquery, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have installed the latest version of joomla 2.5 and the latest version of virtuemart 2.0.8e.
However, when I go to edit the product status of a product that I have entered and change the Availability Date, in chrome it wont work but in firefox it does.When I say it doesnt work i mean that when i click on the date field, the datepicker opens, but when i click the date, it wont return it in the field. It seems to be a known issue but without a solution yet. I have been searching on the internet and also I tried to fix this issue by my self with no success. 
This is the code that is being used when I click on the date:
It seems that it is using datepicker from jquery 1.6.4 from ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
        $(".datepicker").live( "focus", function() {                
            $("#product_available_date_text").datepicker({              
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                '.$yearRange.'
                dateFormat:"'.strtolower($jsDateFormat).'",
                altField: $("#product_available_date_text").prev(),
                altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
            });
        });
        $(".js-date-reset").click(function() {              
            $(this).prev("input").val("'.JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_NEVER').'").prev("input").val("0");
        });
    });
```

I have located this code in administrator/components/com_virtuemart/helpers/config.php in line 1238.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess the answer is

locate the file under administrator/components/com_virtuemart/helpers/config.php and change the line 1242 were it is :

```
$display .= '<input id="'.$id.'_text" class="datepicker" type="date" value="'.$formatedDate.'" />';
```

and replace

```
type="date" to type="text".
```